# SQL running faster on micro instance (vs. small instance)

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

**Background:**
I was running my webpage in a EC2 micro instance (613MB) on us-east-1b.
Then I purchased a small instance (1,7GB) on us-east-1d.

**Issue**
To my surprise in the second the DB queries are running slowler. How that's possible?
Both are clons, same database (estructure and data), same code and same files.

I have a complex sql function (which check the names in the database similar to what the user wrote). In the micro it takes 1,5", and on the small 2,5"?? How that's possible? 
(I wrote things I didn't wrote before to avoid any cache related advantage toward the micro).

Do you know what's behind this?

See the function running slowler:

```
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `levenshtein`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `levenshtein`( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) ) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT; 
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR; 

    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256); 
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0; 
    IF s1 = s2 THEN 
      RETURN 0; 
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s2_len; 
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s1_len; 
    ELSE 
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO 
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
          SET c = c + 1; 
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
          END IF; 
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; 
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
            IF c > c_temp THEN  
              SET c = c_temp;  
            END IF; 
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1; 
        END WHILE; 
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN c; 
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Are they both EBS backed? Is your query CPU bound or IO bound? micro instances can burst briefly to 2 ECUs, whereas a small is always 1 ECU

Comment: I've added the function for better understanding